# General solution to $f(kx,ky)=kf(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$ f(kx,ky)=kf(x,y)$$
for all $k,x,y\geq 0$, one possible set of solutions is
$$ f(x,y)=x^ay^b $$
for any $a+b=1$.

Is this general form unique? Or do other solutions exist?

Either a counter example or a suggestion on how I might prove uniqueness would be much appreciated.

Comment: $f(x,y)=xg(y/x)$ maybe?

Comment: $f(x,y)=0$ is not of the given form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the definition of an homogeneous function with degree one. The example you propose is by no means unique. For instance, $f(x,y)=x+y$ does the trick.

More generally, any differentiable function satisfying
$$
x f'_x + y f'_y = f
$$

will work.

Comment: I would expect a down vote to come along with some comment, especially in such a straightforward issue. It is through discussion that answers can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

What about

$$f(x,y)=x\,\phi\left(\frac yx\right)$$ where $\phi$ is an arbitrary univariate function ? (In particular, $x\left(\dfrac yx\right)^a$.)